# tasmota on ESP8266 is not connecting to cloud mqtt server

Tags: mqtt, tasmota

I am trying to connect ESP8266 using tasmota, to a cloud mqtt broker and getting message

```
 MQT: Connect failed to broker.hivemq.com:1883, rc -2. Retry in 10 sec
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it turns out that in versions after 9.1 Tasmota has changed the default value of MQTTWifiTimeout from 2000ms to 200ms and because ESP8266 is not a very fast MCU this low timeout value is too short.
So setting:

```
MqttWifiTimeout 1000
```

from console does the trick.